# Creating mapping id between two different data frame

Tags: r, seurat

I have data frame which is coming out of seurat analysis pipeline,

- one set is for the cells which are annotated which results in one data frame that contains the cells, its cell type annotation and numerical cluster associated with each cell type cluster.
- The second data frame is the genes which is how the cell types are annotated based on the expression of genes which are probable markers for the annotated cell types.

That was the background.

The cluster for the cell type

```
> table(seurat@meta.data$louvain)

      CD4 T cells   CD14+ Monocytes           B cells       CD8 T cells          NK cells FCGR3A+ Monocytes 
             1144               480               342               316               154               150 
  Dendritic cells    Megakaryocytes 
               37                15 
> table(seurat@meta.data$seurat_clusters)

   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
1140  467  351  247  219  167   32   15
```

The cluster for the gene

```
table(cl_markers$seurat_clusters)

  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
341 691 299 640 229 858 815 439
```

The common factor here is the cluster number for both the gene and cell type.

Now I can't map directly each cell type to the gene due to the differences in the dimension.

```
> dim(mke_cluster)
[1] 2638    2
> dim(mke_gene)
[1] 4312    3
```

My small subset cluster dataframe

```
 head(mke_cluster)
                         louvain seurat_clusters
AAACATACAACCAC-1     CD4 T cells               0
AAACATTGAGCTAC-1         B cells               2
AAACATTGATCAGC-1     CD4 T cells               0
AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1 CD14+ Monocytes               5
AAACCGTGTATGCG-1        NK cells               3
AAACGCACTGGTAC-1     CD8 T cells               0
```

Gene subset

```
head(mke_gene)
      seurat_clusters  gene avg_log2FC
LDHB                0  LDHB  1.6653235
RPS12               2 RPS12  0.8438077
RPS25               2 RPS25  0.9089848
CD3D                0  CD3D  1.5250903
RPS27               1 RPS27  0.7858780
RPS6                0  RPS6  0.7065248
```

My objective is

- Another column in the mke_gene data frame where the gene are labelled with the `*louvain*`.

I was not sure how to map I tried merging I'm not sure if this is the right approach or not since both the df are different dimension, which is by default biologically.

```
> merged_data <- merge(mke_cluster, mke_gene, by.x = "seurat_clusters", by.y = "seurat_clusters")
```

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated

```
dput(head(cl_markers, n = 10))
structure(list(p_val = c(6.64840265863089e-242, 1.13459111505844e-224, 
5.8379603130071e-204, 1.10871523912512e-193, 1.2932367269787e-184, 
3.62844688134858e-184, 2.7796055265616e-178, 9.24017697438729e-173, 
9.23182535159467e-168, 4.61251612799725e-164), avg_log2FC = c(1.66532350813551, 
0.843807664890472, 0.90898477536885, 1.52509026397192, 0.785877979378442, 
0.706524751609463, 0.687290625486455, 0.656853693459277, 0.759283189548348, 
0.824286733662864), pct.1 = c(0.936, 1, 1, 0.879, 0.999, 1, 1, 
1, 0.996, 0.997), pct.2 = c(0.477, 0.989, 0.967, 0.247, 0.989, 
0.993, 0.993, 0.993, 0.978, 0.953), p_val_adj = c(9.1176194060464e-238, 
1.55597825519115e-220, 8.00617877325794e-200, 1.52049207893619e-189, 
1.77354484737859e-180, 4.97605205308144e-180, 3.81195101912658e-174, 
1.26719787026747e-168, 1.26605252871769e-163, 6.32560461793543e-160
), cluster = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), 
    gene = c("LDHB", "RPS12", "RPS25", "CD3D", "RPS27", "RPS6", 
    "RPS3", "RPS14", "TPT1", "RPL31")), row.names = c("LDHB", 
"RPS12", "RPS25", "CD3D", "RPS27", "RPS6", "RPS3", "RPS14", "TPT1", 
"RPL31"), class = "data.frame")
```

#######################################################

```
 dput(head(seurat@meta.data, n = 10))
structure(list(orig.ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "SeuratProject", class = "factor"), 
    nCount_RNA = c(2419, 4903, 3147, 2639, 980, 2163, 2175, 2260, 
    1275, 1103), nFeature_RNA = c(779L, 1352L, 1129L, 960L, 521L, 
    781L, 782L, 790L, 532L, 550L), n_genes = c(781, 1352, 1131, 
    960, 522, 782, 783, 790, 533, 550), percent_mito = c(0.0301777590066195, 
    0.0379359573125839, 0.00889736227691174, 0.0174308456480503, 
    0.0122448978945613, 0.016643550246954, 0.0381609201431274, 
    0.0309734512120485, 0.0117647061124444, 0.0290117859840393
    ), n_counts = c(2419, 4903, 3147, 2639, 980, 2163, 2175, 
    2260, 1275, 1103), louvain = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L), levels = c("CD4 T cells", "CD14+ Monocytes", 
    "B cells", "CD8 T cells", "NK cells", "FCGR3A+ Monocytes", 
    "Dendritic cells", "Megakaryocytes"), class = "factor"), 
    percent.mt = c(3.01777594047127, 3.79359575769937, 0.889736256752463, 
    1.74308450170519, 1.22448979591837, 1.66435506241331, 3.81609195402299, 
    3.09734513274336, 1.17647058823529, 2.9011786038078), RNA_snn_res.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("0", "1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), seurat_clusters = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("0", "1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("AAACATACAACCAC-1", 
"AAACATTGAGCTAC-1", "AAACATTGATCAGC-1", "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1", "AAACCGTGTATGCG-1", 
"AAACGCACTGGTAC-1", "AAACGCTGACCAGT-1", "AAACGCTGGTTCTT-1", "AAACGCTGTAGCCA-1", 
"AAACGCTGTTTCTG-1"), class = "data.frame")
```

So here was my code to generate mke_cluster and mke_gene

```
mke_cluster = seurat@meta.data %>% select(louvain,seurat_clusters)
mke_gene = cl_markers %>% select(cluster,gene,avg_log2FC) 
names(mke_gene)[1] = "seurat_clusters"
```

**UPDATE**

Seurat dataframe

```
    dput(head(seurat, n = 10))
structure(list(orig.ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "SeuratProject", class = "factor"), 
    nCount_RNA = c(2419, 4903, 3147, 2639, 980, 2163, 2175, 2260, 
    1275, 1103), nFeature_RNA = c(779L, 1352L, 1129L, 960L, 521L, 
    781L, 782L, 790L, 532L, 550L), n_genes = c(781, 1352, 1131, 
    960, 522, 782, 783, 790, 533, 550), percent_mito = c(0.0301777590066195, 
    0.0379359573125839, 0.00889736227691174, 0.0174308456480503, 
    0.0122448978945613, 0.016643550246954, 0.0381609201431274, 
    0.0309734512120485, 0.0117647061124444, 0.0290117859840393
    ), n_counts = c(2419, 4903, 3147, 2639, 980, 2163, 2175, 
    2260, 1275, 1103), louvain = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L), levels = c("CD4 T cells", "CD14+ Monocytes", 
    "B cells", "CD8 T cells", "NK cells", "FCGR3A+ Monocytes", 
    "Dendritic cells", "Megakaryocytes"), class = "factor"), 
    percent.mt = c(3.01777594047127, 3.79359575769937, 0.889736256752463, 
    1.74308450170519, 1.22448979591837, 1.66435506241331, 3.81609195402299, 
    3.09734513274336, 1.17647058823529, 2.9011786038078), RNA_snn_res.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("0", "1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), seurat_clusters = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L), levels = c("0", "1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("AAACATACAACCAC-1", 
"AAACATTGAGCTAC-1", "AAACATTGATCAGC-1", "AAACCGTGCTTCCG-1", "AAACCGTGTATGCG-1", 
"AAACGCACTGGTAC-1", "AAACGCTGACCAGT-1", "AAACGCTGGTTCTT-1", "AAACGCTGTAGCCA-1", 
"AAACGCTGTTTCTG-1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you use `library(dplyr)` and then do `mke_gene %>% inner_join(mke_cluster, by = "seurat_clusters")`?

Comment: `Warning message:
In inner_join(., mke_cluster, by = "seurat_clusters") :
  Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between `x` and `y`.
ℹ Row 1 of `x` matches multiple rows in `y`.
ℹ Row 1 of `y` matches multiple rows in `x`.
ℹ If a many-to-many relationship is expected, set `relationship = "many-to-many"` to silence this warning.`

Comment: While that warning is not technically an error, it does confirm that you are getting too many matches.  How do you associate some row in `mke_gene` with (say) `AAACATACAACCAC-1` in `mke_cluster`?  If `seurat_clusters` is not enough on its own, then what else is necessary?  We can certainly tell you how to _use_ that info in constructing a certain dataset, but I for one am a programmer and not a geneticist, so I can't really point you to the genetic _concepts_ contained in your own data.

Comment: would it be helpful if i share the data in pastebin etc ? and the share the link

Comment: Just edit your question to add a new section to the bottom, where you paste the output from `dput(head(seurat@meta.data, n = 10))` as a code block, and below it the output from `dput(head(cl_markers, n = 10))` as a separate code block.

Comment: @Greg i added 10 from each of them

Comment: Perfect!  Now do you have the dataset itself?  The "data" as opposed to the `meta.data`?  Is `seurat` itself the dataset?

Comment: this is the info which i want to map gene associated with each louvain cluster I can post it in a paste bin and share if you want. "seurat itself the dataset" yes it has multiple layer mean seurat single cell object which is generated from h5ad format

Comment: Can you show us what the `seurat` dataset looks like?  Can you include the output from `dput(head(seurat, n = 10))`, like you did with those other two examples?

Comment: okay will add this

Comment: @Greg due to some update issue i was not able to create the seurat object here is the output after i reinstalled some libraries again

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a mistake in your `mke_gene` example table or does cluster 0 really have two different labels, CD4 on the first and third rows and CD8 on the sixth row? How did you set the labels?

If you just want to add the cluster annotations in the genes table and the annotations are unique, you can avoid the multiple matches problem like this:

```
clusters <- unique(mke_cluster)
merged_data <- left_join(mke_gene, clusters, by = "seurat_clusters")
```

Comment: its not mistake that how the cluster are assigned based on gene expression